# Webpage is Offset in Firefox, but not any other browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have a weird situation with my website that i cannot work out. I have spent the last hour going through Google and Stackoverflow but i havent been able to find anyone else with my issue.

I have developed the site and was testing in other browsers - IE, Chrome and Safari the site all worked as expected. I then went to open it in Firefox and the whole Content is offset. I've attached an image to show what i mean. It's almost as if i set a huge margin in the CSS file (the CSS rule for the Div has no margins).
Is there anything in particular i should be checking or including for Firefox? I ran the site through the W3C Validator to make sure i didn't have any open tags or anything and have looked into the "Inspect Element" tools in both Firefox and Chrome but cannot pinpoint the problem.

The site was done in ASP.Net. If anyone wants to check out the live version its at www.waspeedcars.com.au

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm sure its something simple as 3/4 browsers worked fine.

[image: Firefox Problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MainData` div seems to be subtly overlapping with the floating li elements in the menu and getting pushed over by them. Adding `clear:both` to the rules for `#MainData` fixes it.

Comment: Thank you for that. I was adding the rule to the Content Div and not MainData, didnt think of going up a level (its been a long day!)
On another note, the background now seems to have disappeared on all browsers?

Comment: The Content and NavRight divs are both floating, so their parent MainContent doesn't cover their height. You can add `overflow:hidden` to MainContent to fix that.